# right format for html_safe string in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, html-safe

I've been trying this for a while now...

```
<%= ("<h3>(#{@user.first_name.capitalize}" + I18n.t('helpers.s_page') + 
      I18n.t('find_something.empty_user_other')</h3>").html_safe %>
```

Can you tell me what the right way of putting it is... thanks for any help.

Chris.

Comment: **Comment on behalf of Christophe Harris**: Am I supposed to acknowledge or '+1' people if they give me an answer? How come people have large numbers besides their avatars?

Comment: Yes, you should Vote Up questions if you like them. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) (plus you'll get a badge for it!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<h3>
  <%= @user.first_name.capitalize %>
  <%= I18n.t 'helpers.s_page' %>
  <%= I18n.t 'find_something.empty_user_other' %>
</h3>
```

And that way you don't need to use `html_safe` at all, assuming those strings in the `<% %>` sections don't contain HTML.